# Problem with closing a running python thread

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a single-line encrypted code in form of string and a function that decodes & execute the encrypted code (the code establishes backdoor connection to another computer in the network, but that isn't very relevent here) Once the encrypted code runs the program won't proceed to next line because the code does not stop (in order to keep the connection alive).

What I want to do is run the code for 10 seconds, then terminate it, and re-run it.

But I am not being able to terminate the code because it's encrypted and can't be changed. I thought I could run it on a separate thread then forcibly terminate it after 10 seconds, but the problem is all the solutions mentioned on the internet would require changing the encrypted code slightly.

Python does not seem to have a way to forcibly close a running thread after 'n' seconds, which would solve my problem very easily.

Following code demonstrates my problem:

```
import threading, time

encrypted_code = ")'cba'(tnirp :eurT elihw"

def decrypt_and_execute(encrypted_code):
    exec(encrypted_code[::-1])

def run(encrypted_code, run_time):
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=decrypt_and_execute, args=(encrypted_code,))
    my_thread.start()
    time.sleep(run_time)
    # CODE TO STOP 'my_thread' without changing 'encrypted_code' NEEDED HERE#

while True:
    threading.Thread(target=run, args=(encrypted_code, 10)).start()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Above was my attempted solution (encrypted code here is an infinite while loop that keeps printing abc).
Any code I tried to stop 'my_thread' without closing the whole application, did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that technique of a thread with traces works for you, is a Thread subclass that you can stop. From https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/

Or use subprocesses, they have terminate. That same post covers that too nicely.

Edit: for some reason, this failed to kill the thread in the case in question. The multiprocess module solved the issue: killing processes is a reliable way to stop things on all operating systems, and multiprocess module has a spawn method that gives a Thread like API for subprocesses, and can start new processes with Python code also on Windows without having Python installed.

Anyway for other cases this technique with threading should work too. Threads are rarely actually needed but sometimes they truly are.

```
# Python program using 
# traces to kill threads 

import sys 

import trace 
import threading 
import time 

class thread_with_trace(threading.Thread): 
  def __init__(self, *args, **keywords): 
    threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **keywords) 
    self.killed = False

  def start(self): 
    self.__run_backup = self.run 
    self.run = self.__run       
    threading.Thread.start(self) 

  def __run(self): 
    sys.settrace(self.globaltrace) 
    self.__run_backup() 
    self.run = self.__run_backup 

  def globaltrace(self, frame, event, arg): 
    if event == 'call': 
      return self.localtrace 

    else: 
      return None 

  def localtrace(self, frame, event, arg): 
    if self.killed: 
      if event == 'line': 
        raise SystemExit() 

    return self.localtrace 
  
  def kill(self): 
    self.killed = True

def func(): 
  while True: 
    print('thread running') 

t1 = thread_with_trace(target = func) 
t1.start() 

time.sleep(2) 
t1.kill() 
t1.join() 

if not t1.isAlive(): 
  print('thread killed')
```

Comment: The solution works for an infinite while loop, but did not work for the backdoor. The backdoor just keeps running and never stops. Any idea why does that happen?

Comment: I would probably use a process and call terminate on it: "Popen.terminate() #Stop the child. On POSIX OSs the method sends SIGTERM to the child. On Windows the Win32 API function TerminateProcess() is called to stop the child." https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Is it possible to use that from an executable running on a computer that does not have python installed on it?

Comment: I think so, at least on Unix like systems by using os.fork() .. are you on win or posix?

Comment: The multiprocessing module provides spawn to start new processes with the Python interpreter, also on Windows, without needing Python installed in the system. It is a threading like API for subprocesses, https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Yes, multiprocessing is the thing that finally worked for me.